# Powershell menu that loops when the script is launched via PSEXEC (with display return via CMD)

Tags: powershell, loops, switch-statement, default, read-host

We have Powershell scripts which are run on remote workstations via a private tool (and via PSEXEC).
All feedback (messages, errors) is given in the CMD window.
The problem is that when a script uses a menu (via "Read-Host" + "Switch"), this menu sometimes loops endlessly.
The CMD sends data that the Powershell interprets as a user choice, and as a result, it enters the "Default" part of the "Switch" and does so endlessly.

```
$choix2 = Read-Host "Faire un choix : O/N"
switch ($choix2) {
    O {
        Action
    }
    N {
        Action
    }
    default {
        Write-Host "Invalid choice"
        Pause
    }
}
```

In "Default", the "PAUSE" command is used to limit this problem. When the CMD sends data, the "PAUSE" stops and the user can enter a choice. But sometimes it doesn't work and the menu loops back to "Default".

I'd like to know if there's a more functional method of correcting this problem completely. To completely remove this "parasitic" data, sent by cmd, which is blocking me from using the Powershell menus.

Regards

Comment: The op may be entering lower case letters, spaces, or more than one letter.  Your code is only looking for two character O or N. Try : switch ($choix2.Trim().ToUpper().Substring(1))

Comment: @jdweng, the `.Trim()` tip is helpful, but there is no need for `.ToUpper()`: PowerShell is _generally_ case-_insensitive_ by default, and `switch` is no exception.

Comment: My problem is that it's not the user who sends a response, but the CMD interpreter. Sometimes, the user doesn't have time to choose a response, it goes straight into "Default".
I'd like to filter out this "parasitic" CMD response, if that's possible.

Comment: If the script is run remotely by a private tool or PSEXEC, from where is it getting input? Is there a user session on the remote system? I am sure there are reasons a private tool and PSEXEC are used, but it might be more sustainabe to use PowerShell Remoting.

Comment: I completely agree with you, but the security department hasn't validated the use of PowerShell Remoting (much to my regret).
To put it simply :
1. The tool copies the Powershell script locally, on the remote machine.
2. Run a cmd with PSEXEC then execute the script.
3. The results of the script are sent from the remote machine to the cmd.

This is where it blocks, during a menu, sometimes, without the user doing anything, a choice is made. Probably by the CMD interpreter. As a result, you're back in "Default".